# While updating java 8 to java 17 javax.sql.DataSource having errore.I injected datasource using application context

Tags: spring, java-17

in eclipse i can see an error as like "The package javax.sql is accessible from more than one module: , java.sql ".How we can solve this issue

Comment: If your project is a brand-new, I suggest to update all your dependencies with latest java-17 supported, 'couse javax package has been removed, so if your spring-* reference javax.* is probabile that is outdated version for java-17

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace  `javax` by `jarkata` everywhere needed for libraries import. I think this should solve your issue.